# Почему здесь запятая и тире? Что лишнее?

Tags: пунктуация, синтаксис, тире, запятые

*Илья Муромец получил исцеление от трех вещих старцев **— калик перехожих, —** которые предсказали...*

По сути этот фрагмент — пояснительная конструкция, которая по правилам выделяется либо двумя тире, либо двумя запятыми. Что здесь лишнее: тире или запятая?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Илья Муромец получил исцеление от трех вещих старцев — калик перехожих, — которые предсказали...**

Здесь использовано **оформление вставной конструкции**, так как информация справочного характера.  Вставка всегда выделяется двумя тире, а запятая в этом случае  "перенесенная".

Вставку удобно определить **по исключительной интонации**: две паузы, немного пониженный  тон.

Другой вариант оформления — **это обособление приложения одним тире**, но тогда будет обозначена тесная связь этого приложения с определяемым словом (встроенная интонация, произношение без паузы).

**Илья Муромец получил исцеление от трех вещих старцев — калик перехожих,  которые предсказали.**

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! А что значит запятая "перенесенная"? Она, наверное, относится к придаточному определительному... Почему нельзя оформить вставную конструкцию так же, как обособленное приложения, т.е. одним тире, аргументируя это тем, что второе тире из-за запятой поглощается?

Comment: Вставка - это всегда два тире и интонация исключения, это как бы второй план речи. Поэтому вставочные тире запятыми не поглощаются, они обозначают две обязательные паузы.  В этой теме мы выбираем только запятые: нет запятых, одна запятая. две запятые. Перенесенная запятая - это та, которая стояла бы перед придаточным, если бы вставки не было. 
 http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=125#pp125

Answer (score 1):

Вот что пишет Розенталь ([§ 19. Обособленные приложения](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=111))

Примечание. Одно тире (первое или второе) опускается:

1) если по условиям контекста после обособленного приложения ставится запятая: Если бы он привлёк к решению вопроса свой прибор — весы, то понял бы источник ошибки; Используя специальное устройство для дыхания человека под водой — акваланг, можно погружаться на глубину в десятки метров; Среди актёров передвижной труппы Сергея Эйзенштейна были юноши, впоследствии ставшие известными кинорежиссёрами, — Григорий Александров, Иван Пырьев, а также актёр Максим Штраух (Газ.);

Корректно: **Илья Муромец получил исцеление от трех вещих старцев — калик перехожих, которые предсказали...**

Comment: Вы считаете, что два тире - это ошибка? Почему обособленное приложение нельзя оформить как вставку, если это информация второго плана?  Кали́ка (Кали́ки перехо́жие) — старинное название странников, поющих духовные стихи и былины. Это дополнительный, поясняющий материал.  Думаю, что автор имеет право на выбор. Зачем нам жесткие и формальные  уставки, если правила позволяют обозначить смысловые оттенки?

Comment: @Jasmin Запятая у Вас, как Вы пишете, "перенесенная", то есть стоит не на своем месте. Я не знаком с правилами, позволяющими такие манипуляции (можете дать ссылку?). А примечание Розенталя не оставляет места для альтернатив. Не так ли?

Comment: У Розенталя есть два способа оформления обособленных членов: а)  в виде вставки; б)  в виде приложения . Правила различные, вот здесь автор и делает ВЫБОР, в котором вы ему отказываете.  Приложение может быть оформлена как вставка, но не наоборот. Вставная  конструкция содержит дополнительные сведения, вот мы и решаем,  что означает наше приложение.  И должны при этом помнить, что в устной речи при наличии только одного тире пауза перед приложением вообще не делается. А если я хочу выделить приложение паузами? Тогда нужно оформлять его как вставку (ссылку я дала в комментарии к своему ответу).

Comment: @Jasmin  Во-первых, спасибо за разъяснение. Я делаю для себя вывод, что "перенесенная" запятая может ставиться только в случае вставки, а в случае приложения тире "поглощает" эту запятую. Мне не импонирует идея считать "калик перехожих" вставкой, но не могу доказать, что это неверно. А что не запрещено, то разрешено. Выходит, Вы правы.

Comment: Я бы еще добавила, что при обособлении приложения используется ВСТРОЕННАЯ конструкция, при которой приложение теряет свой обособленный статус и входит в первую часть предложения без увеличенной паузы. Поэтому мы имеем две формы: вставочную и встроенную (обычно используется для приложений).

Comment: Сравним: (1) Илья Муромец получил исцеление от трех вещих стАрцев — калИк перехожих. Приложение обособлено увеличенной паузой. (2 )Илья Муромец получил исцеление от трех вещих старцев — калИк перехожих, которые предсказали...  При наличии только одного тире приложение интонационно не обособляется, а пауза делается перед союзным словом.